# jquery image gallery next/prev issue

Tags: jquery

I have below code in my page I am able to run next image click but prev image click not working. On click "next" it shows me div1 - div2 - div3  but on click prev its not showing me anything.

My HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img.prev>
    <img.next>
    <div1>
    <div2>
    <div3>
</div>
```

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

// this works fine
$('.next').live('click', function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
}) ;

// this is not working
$('.prev').live('click',function(){
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(0)
        .prev()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
});
```

Comment: You are calling .prev() from the first element. There is nothing previous to the first, is there?

Comment: But there no next() after my last div3 but when i click next then it fadeout div3 and fadein div1. that works fine.

Comment: there is no `prev` for `first` : $('#slideshow > div:first')

Answer (score 0):

Thank about what your code is doing. In the first example the following happens:

```
$('.next').live('click',function(){
  $('#slideshow > div:first')   //get first div, div1, in slideshow
 .fadeOut(0)                    //fade div1 out
 .next()                        //get the next div, div2
 .fadeIn(1000)                  //fade div2 in
 .end()                         //end
 .appendTo('#slideshow');       //append the original div, div1, to the end of the show
}) ;
```

A problem I see with this is that you are constantly adding more images to your slideshow. This will result in a very large number of DOM elements. I don't think you want to append at all.

Regardless of that, your code doesn't work in the second case because...

```
$('.prev').live('click',function(){
 $('#slideshow > div:first')    //get first div, div1
 .fadeOut(0)                    //fade it out
 .prev()                        //previous is nothing because you already have the first one! This is no doubt why it breaks
 .fadeIn(1000)
 .end()
 .appendTo('#slideshow');       //again you are appending. Seems like a bad idea
}) ;
```

If I were going to do this I would use classes instead. Untested, but would look like this.

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img.prev>
    <img.next>
    <div1 class="active">
    <div2>
    <div3>
</div>

$('.next').live('click',function(){
  $('#slideshow > div.active')  //get active div
  .fadeOut(0)                    //fade out
  .removeClass('active')
  .next()                        //get the next div
  .fadeIn(1000)                  //fade it in
  .addClass('active');           //make new div the active one
}) ;

$('.next').live('click',function(){
  $('#slideshow > div.active')  //get active div
  .fadeOut(0)                    //fade out
  .removeClass('active')
  .prev()                        //get the prev div
  .fadeIn(1000)                  //fade it in
  .addClass('active');           //make new div the active one
}) ;
```

Comment: Is there any way to loop it in reverse?

Comment: Also, `live` has been deprecated. I wouldn't use it unless you are stuck on jQuery < 1.4. You use `on` instead.

Comment: @user1941729 - I'm not a free software development company. Try fixing it yourself, if you can't solve it, then post another SO question. Here is a hint, use an 'if` statement. `if (div:last) then go back to beginning of slideshow`

Answer (score 0):

`.prev` is not working because the first element cannot have any previous siblings by definition.  `.next` works because the first child always has three elements -- it appears to cycle because you keep moving the first div to the end as expected.  For `.prev` to work, you should select the last element and prepend it:

```
$("#slideshow > div:first").hide();
$("#slideshow > div:last").prependTo("#slideshow").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Prepending and postpending images ad-infinitum is going to cause him problems down the line. One of which is that depending on the order of next/prev clicked he will end up with an out of order slideshow.